# selected html filtrar campos unicos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho o seguinte selected, como faço para que ele filtre os campos únicos por exemplo ele esta repetindo o mesmo option `<option value='967'>GOIANIA - GO</option>` varias vezes quero que ele mostre apenas uma vez os dados repetidos, e possível fazer isso com jquery.

```
"<option selected="selected" value="0">Cidade</option><option value='967'>GOIANIA - GO</option><option value='967'>GOIANIA - GO</option><option value='967'>GOIANIA - GO</option><option value='967'>GOIANIA - GO</option>"
```

Comment: De onde vem esse HTML? não seria melhor fazer isso no servidor ou onde esse HTML é gerado?

Comment: esse selected esta sendo gerado através de um ajax que faz a requisição para o método e pega o retorno da lista em json ultilizando asp mvc , la no controller tenho a lista detro dela dois atributos Id,Nome ultilizei o distinct porem ele esta retornando dados unicos  egm.LstCid = egm.LstCid.Distinct().ToList();  , pensei que houvesse uma maneira fácil de fácil ultilizando jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entenda que o script abaixo apenas trata o sintoma, o problema ainda irá continuar, o ideal é que realize o filtro na sua consulta que popula o select.

```js
var values = [];
var select = document.querySelector("select");
[].forEach.call(select.options, function (option, indice) {
  if (values.indexOf(option.value) > -1) {
    select.removeChild(option);
  } else {
    values.push(option.value);
  }  
});
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="">Selecione...</option>
  <option value="1">Opção 1</option>
  <option value="2">Opção 2</option>
  <option value="3">Opção 3</option>
  <option value="4">Opção 4</option>
  <option value="2">Opção 2</option>
  <option value="3">Opção 3</option>
  <option value="4">Opção 4</option>
  <option value="5">Opção 5</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT - Sugestão**

Lendo o seu comentario, acredito que o `Distinct` irá funcionar se você diminuir os campos do seu `select`.

```
egm.LstCid.Select(cid => new { Id = cid.Id, Nome = cid.Nome }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: realemte ultilizei sua solução  egm.LstCid.Select(cid => new { Id = cid.Id, Nome = cid.Nome }).Distinct().ToList(); e o distinct funcionou :)